# How can I put an Image for a specific user in vuejs template?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm actually working on profile picture for users.
I now want to put this profil picture next to their name in my chat which is working with pusher and vuejs.
My img is like this :

```
<img class="profil_pic" src="{{url('uploads/logo_'.Auth::user()->firstName."_".Auth::user()->lastName.".png")}}" onerror="this.src='images/user.jpg'" alt="">
```

I can not just past it in the file it's not working and it would be for every user, but I want it to be for the auth user. I'm kinda new to vue.js any help would be thankful.

This is my chatMessage.vue :

```
<template>
    <ul class="chat messages" >
        <li class="clearfix list-group-item" v-for="message in messages" v-bind:class="{
            classForUser: (message.user.id === currentuserid),
            classForNotUser: (message.user.id !== currentuserid)}" >
            <div class="chat-body clearfix" >
                <div class="header">
                    <strong class="primary-font"
                            v-bind:class="{
                                classForAuthorSameAsUser: (message.user.id === currentuserid),
                                classForAuthorDiffThanUser: (message.user.id !== currentuserid)
                            }">
                        {{ message.user.firstName }}
                        {{ message.user.lastName}}
                        :
                    </strong>
                    {{ message.human_readable_time}}
                </div>
                <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['messages','currentuserid']
    };

</script>

<style scoped>
    .classForAuthorSameAsUser {
        color: lightseagreen ;
    }
    .classForAuthorDiffThanUser {
        color: black;
    }
    .classForUser{
        width: 70%;
        left: 30%;
    }
    .classForNotUser{
        width: 70%;
    }
</style>
```

And this is the html of my chat :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel-body panel-content" id="mess_cont" :userid="{{Auth::user()->id}}">
                <chat-messages id="mess" :messages="messages" :currentuserid="{{Auth::user()->id}}"></chat-messages>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">A
                <chat-form
                    v-on:messagesent="addMessage"
                    :user="{{ Auth::user() }}">
                </chat-form>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I think I have to use again the thing that help me to get the user id, but I don't really know how it works with vue.js.
Thanks for your time

And now I have this :

```
<template>
    <ul class="chat messages" >
        <li class="clearfix list-group-item" v-for="message in messages" v-bind:class="{

                    classForUser: (message.user.id === currentuserid),
                    classForNotUser: (message.user.id !== currentuserid)}" >

            <div class="chat-body clearfix" >
                <div class="header">
                    <strong class="primary-font"
                            v-bind:class="{
                                classForAuthorSameAsUser: (message.user.id === currentuserid),
                                classForAuthorDiffThanUser: (message.user.id !== currentuserid)
                            }">
                        <img class="profil_pic" :src="`path/to/uploads/logo_${user.firstName}_${user.lastName}.png`" alt="Auth image"/>

                        {{ message.user.firstName }}
                        {{ message.user.lastName}}
                        :
                    </strong>
                    {{ message.human_readable_time}}
                </div>
                <p>

                    {{ message.message }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</template>

<script>

    export default {
        props: ['messages','currentuserid'],
        data() {
            return {
                user: null,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            this:$http.get('/api/get-auth')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.user = response.data.auth
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    // handle error
                }),
        }

    };




</script>

<style scoped>
    .classForAuthorSameAsUser {
        color: lightseagreen ;
    }
    .classForAuthorDiffThanUser {
        color: black;
    }
    .classForUser{
        width: 70%;
        left: 30%;
    }
    .classForNotUser{
        width: 70%;
    }
</style>
```

And it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, what you want to achieve is to take this img tag (with blade's logic):

```
<img class="profil_pic" src="{{url('uploads/logo_'.Auth::user()->firstName."_".Auth::user()->lastName.".png")}}" onerror="this.src='images/user.jpg'" alt="">
```

And put it inside your `chatMessage.vue` component. If that's it, you can do so like this:

**1.** Create a function inside a controller in order to return the authenticated user information:

```
public function getAuth()
{
    return response()->json([
        'auth' => auth()->user(),
    ], 200);
}
```

**2.** Create a new route in order to get that information inside your `api.php` file:

```
Route::get('/get-auth', 'YourController@getAuth');
```

**3.** Create a new param inside the data() returned object in the `chatMessage.vue` component:

```
data() {
    return {
        user: null,        
    }
},
```

**4.** Create a method inside your `chatMessage.vue` component with the necessary code to fetch that data:

```
fetchAuth() {
    this.$http.get('/api/get-auth')
        .then((response) => {
            this.user = response.data.auth
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // handle error
        });
}
```

**5.** Call that method inside your `created()` life cycle method:

```
created() {
    this.fetchAuth();
}
```

**6.** Create the img tag like this:

```
<img class="profil_pic" :src="`path/to/uploads/logo_${user.firstName}_${user.lastName}.png`" alt="Auth image"/>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your time and sorry for late feedback. So I'm at the 3rd point but I don't really know where to put the data field. When I put it between the script tag I have "Unnecessary label user" and "statement expected"

Comment: Sorry, i didn't explain some things assuming you would understand. My bad. Remember that "path/to/uploads" it's just an example. You HAVE to put the path to that directory.

Comment: My bad on this one I should have notice so I put :                         <img class="profil_pic" :src="`uploads/logo_${user.firstName}_${user.lastName}.png`" alt="Auth image"/>
, uploads is my folder where the photos are, I did Npm run dev and my chat is empty now, no message in the console I have $http is not defined

Comment: In your ``app.js`` file put the next code: ``Vue.prototype.$http = require('axios');``

Comment: I still have this :  Uncaught ReferenceError: $http is not defined

Comment: You used ``this:$http`` insted of ``this.$http``

Comment: Yes because when I put a dot, I have an error ": expected" and I also have error when I do NPM run dev

Comment: So it's working now, but I just needed the <img> tag, no need method and data, its working now, thanks for your time and help !